# How to open files when the sources are in a column of another file

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a large three-column Excel file:

1. first column is "data (Excel file) name"
2. second column is the "data source(of that Excel file's data)" and
3. third column is "remarks"

See [large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UehGT.gif)  image

[image: SU603985 example]

I want to check contents of the data by clicking (2nd column) source in my LAN (accessible from my pc).

Presently I am doing copy source and paste in the Run command of Windows7 to do the check. How can I do this by one-clicking (not copy/paste/enter)?

Comment: I have no idea what this means. How many PC's are you using if more than 1? What do you want to achieve by "one clicking"?

Comment: I have added image

Comment: Removed my -1 as question reads better

Comment: Can you re-explain a little. Where is Column B data populated from? An external file? What is the code you're using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want (even a single row of sample data in your question might clarify) but it seems you might want =HYPERLINK (see http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/create-select-edit-or-delete-a-hyperlink-HP010096304.aspx).

Comment: Hyperlinking for every cell is time consuming!

Comment: I have added image

Comment: @ pnuts Is not it too time consuming since it to be done for every source entry i.e. cell? But i have a column of source (B4 to B20000)